# Knockout computed observable with access to observableArray

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm having an issue using a `computedObservable`.  They seem pretty straight forward, but I think my use case might be a little odd.  The issue is when `onBottom()` is called, it doesn't see the items that are in the `container.slides()` array.  Instead, I get "Undefined is not a function".

Since `onTop()` works fine, it makes me think that it's the relationship between `Slide` and `FeaturedContent` that is causing the issue, but I think it should work fine.  Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

**HTML**

```
        <div class="section-block" data-bind="foreach: slides">
            <div class="row well">
                <div class='control'>
                    <a href='#' data-bind="click: moveUp, ifnot: onTop">
                        <i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a href='#' data-bind="click: moveDown, ifnot: onBottom">
                        <i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i>
                    </a>
                    <span class='pull-right'>Remove</span>
                </div>
                <h5 data-bind="text: headline"></h5>
                <p data-bind="text: image"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**JS**

```
var FeaturedContent = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.maxSlides = 14;
    self.slides = ko.observableArray([
        new Slide({}, "I should be last", "someimg", 0, self),
        new Slide({}, "I should be first", "anotherimg", 1, self),
        new Slide({}, "I should be second-", "anotherimg", 2, self),
    ]);

    // ... snipped.

};

var Slide = function(contentItem, headline, image, order, container) {
    var self = this;

    // -- Data
    self.contentItem = contentItem;
    self.headline = headline;
    self.image = image;
    self.position = ko.observable(0);

    self.onBottom = ko.computed(function() {
        return (self.position() === container.slides().length - 1) ? true : false;
    });

    self.onTop = ko.computed(function() {
        return (self.position() === 0) ? true : false;
    });

    return self;
};
```

Comment: Updated to be less verbose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During creating

```
self.slides = ko.observableArray([
    new Slide({}, "I should be last", "someimg", 0, self),
    new Slide({}, "I should be first", "anotherimg", 1, self),
    new Slide({}, "I should be second-", "anotherimg", 2, self),
]);
```

in the `FeaturedContent` your code will create `new Slide` and use `self` to get `container.slides().length` i.e. `self` is the `container` but `slides()` has not created. It's a circle reference. So `container.slides()` is undefined.

try something like this `container.slides() && self.position() === container.slides().length - 1`

Comment: That makes sense.  Thanks.  I opted to create an empty `slides` array and then push new `Slide` instances onto it.